# how to add a stable background image in a simple touch event application in android

Tags: android, background-image

I have to add a stable background image in the application given in the link below

http://obviam.net/index.php/displaying-graphics-with-android/
can anyone help with this

Answer (score 1):

You can include the background image in your xml file. [This](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE953C0B85B50AB62&feature=plcp) is a great resource for learning android.

Comment: thanks.. i already added the line android:background="@drawable/image"> in linear layout in XML file still the background is black can you help me with this

Comment: do you see an entry for image in the R file?

Comment: yes this line,  ( public static final int image1=0x7f020002;) is in R.java then also the backgroung is black .

Comment: I suppose you have the image declared in the <layout> tag. If you still face problems I recommend you watch this video tutorial from 28:00 onwards.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kkoh3gFMKQA&feature=autoplay&list=PLE953C0B85B50AB62&lf=plpp_video&playnext=1

Comment: yes it is in the layout tag only. i will watch the video and let u know.. thanks for the help..:)

Comment: I am not able to do that in applications which has some activity. It works in projects which has only two images in layout